# How can I get the correct sentiment value of sentences in Stanford NLP sentiment analysis

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I downloaded the dataset of Stanford NLP sentiment analysis at http://nlp.stanford.edu/~socherr/stanfordSentimentTreebank.zip

The website of Stanford NLP sentiment analysis is http://nlp.stanford.edu/sentiment/code.html

In the dataset, there is a list of 11855 sentences, and there is sentiment values for phrases, but I couldn't find the true sentiment analysis for each sentence.

For instance, the sentence `Offers that rare combination of entertainment and education .`. What is the true sentiment value of this sentence?

Answer (score 0):

You should get the file trainDevTestTrees_PTB.zip which is available here: http://nlp.stanford.edu/sentiment/code.html

It is the file linked to by "Train,Dev,Test Splits in PTB Tree Format"

That has a sentiment value of 4.  The left most number in the tree represents the overall sentence value.

The trees are of the form (score (sub tree) (sub tree)).

Leaves are of the form (score token).